# В какой директории должен быть обработчик формы?

Tags: wordpress, email

Есть сайт на хостинге www.nic.ru, интегрированный в WordPress. Но php обработчик формы я делал свой. Подскажите, в какой директории он должен быть, чтобы данные отправлялись на почту и все работало?

Comment: Или в WordPress его нужно каким-то особым образом подключать?

Comment: в той, куда указывает action формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо, все решилось, вопрос успешно нашел свой ответ)